# Java Run a task parallel to main thread without blocking it

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, future, completable-future

I'm trying to use Java 8's CompletableFuture features which says it gives the ability to run asynchronously. But in order to execute what's in 'future' needs to call `future.get()` method. Doing that blocks the main thread. as It waits for 30 seconds sleep before executing the line after `future.get()`

Is there a way to achieve this? Do the execution non blocking way 
I'm trying to print

> "I'll run in the main thread."

before

> "I'll run in a separate thread than the main thread."

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Simulate a long-running Job
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("I'll run in a separate thread than the main thread.");
        }
    });
    future.get();
    System.out.println("I'll run in the main thread.");
}
```

Comment: `future.get()` is blocking the main thread, so the thread print statement will always come before the main thread print

Comment: @Lino so any alternative ?

Comment: You can just move the main print statement *before* `future.get()` but this seems simplified so I am not entirely sure what your actual problem is -> *why do you need main-action to come before the thread-action*

Comment: no point moving the statement. actual scenario is to execute a timer parallel to main thread. but the method should go on it's execution with out getting blocked for what's in the future. 
actual scenario is a Rest Call  it get's hit to the endpoint's method. but parallel execution should not block endpoint's method returning the response back

Comment: `CompletableFuture.runAsync(` is already starting your other thread running. Calling `future.get()` is just a way to wait for that thread to finish running, and to get its result, before you continue in the thread doing the calling

Comment: specifications say CompletableFutureis to run tasks non blokingly. yet I was wondering how do we do that.

Comment: @xtratic what is I do not want to wait till that thread finish running. I tried without future.get(). even though then the main thread didn't get blocked,  It still didn't print what's in the thread.

Comment: The `CompletableFuture` *is* running non-blockingly

Comment: @ShenaliSilva when you remove the `get()` call, the main thread doesn’t get block and since there’s nothing else in your simplified example, it will exit. The JVM will terminate when there are only Daemon threads left, which is the reason why you may or may not see a print message, depending on unpredictable timing. That’s not an issue of real life applications. But when you simplified example shall print the message in the background thread, you must wait before terminating.

Answer (score 1):

`CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable)` is already starting your other thread running. Calling `future.get()` is just a way to wait for that thread to finish running, and to get its result, before you continue in the thread doing the calling .

When you start the thread and `get` it immediately, without doing anything between (as you do), then there's no point to running a thread.

Comment: actual scenario is to execute a timer parallel to main thread. but the method should go on it's execution with out getting blocked for what's in the future. actual scenario is a Rest Call it get's hit to the endpoint's method. but parallel execution should not block endpoint's method returning the response back

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve will not be so trivial to accomplish if I understood correctly. You have a call that enters and you want to process this call without interference and along side of this thread you want to run a separate process that is independent of the main process. (Correct me if I misunderstood)

The way I would solve this is with a queue. You main thread post something on a queue and executes what it needs to execute. Then there are separate consumers listening on the queue which will perform the other process without impacting the main thread.